# Undefined function or variable 'setdemorandstream'

Tags: matlab, random, neural-network, undefined, undefined-function

I am working on a feed-forward neural network analysis using MATLAB.
I am getting the following error:

> Undefined function or variable `'setdemorandstream'`.

Code is as follows:

```
setdemorandstream(391418381);
```

Any help in rectifying this error is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the contents of the function, *verbatim*:

```
function setdemorandstream(n)
%SETDEMORANDOMSTREAM Set default stream for reliable example results.
%
%  SETDEMORANDOMSTREAM(N) is less distracting in example code, but
%  equivalent to:
%
%    rs = RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',n);
%    RandStream.setGlobalStream(rs);

% Copyright 2011-2012 The MathWorks, Inc.

rs = RandStream('mcg16807','Seed',n);
RandStream.setGlobalStream(rs);
```

Just save this as a file in your MATLAB path.

However, your errors might not stop there - make sure you have the [neural network toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network.html) installed.

Comment: Thank you! this worked. And yes thank you for your prior attention on the neural network toobox